# Android) run an app to AndoridStudio or when you tried to install the apk app files are not visible

Tags: android, installation, apk, facebook-login

After Facebook Login connect, Run app in AndroidStudio, program execution is going with device, but the file will are not be visible.
I do not know why this is the case happens.

I found a solution on the Internet. but I could not apply this solution in AndroidStudio.
http://tools.android.com/recent/finercontroloveradtbuildprocess

Has anyone experienced the same thing ?
please tell me advice. 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

have a problem with my 'manifest.xml' file?

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.facebooktest.test.facebooktest">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />


    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />

</manifest>
```